# Prove that function is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, contest-math

Let $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \}  $ and $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $m \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ as $A^m= \alpha \times I_n$, with $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ -1,1 \}$.

Prove that $f: M_n(\mathbb{R})\to M_n(\mathbb{R}), f(X)=X+AXA$ is bijective.

I honestly don't have any idea how should I prove this, I'd be grateful for any help. I found the problem in the archives of a contest, but no hints or solving is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(X)=0$. Then $AXA=-X$. Hence show that $A^mXA^m=(-1)^mX$. Yet by the property of $A$, we have $A^mXA^m=\alpha^2X$. Argue that $X=0$ and $f$ is injective. Now, why does it follow that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: Why is $X=0$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat As $\alpha$ is real and $\alpha\neq\pm1$, we have $\alpha^2\neq(-1)^m$. Hence $\alpha^2X=(-1)^mX$ implies that $X=0$.

Comment: @user1551 well... still trying to see **why does it follow that f is also surjective**. Can you give a hint, please? Your injectivity demonstration is quite nice, thanks :)

Comment: @BujancaMihai This is because every injective linear map on a finite dimensional vector space is bijective. The usual proof that appears in introductory textbooks makes use of the rank-nullity theorem: if $f:V\to V$ is injective, then $\operatorname{ker}(f)=0$. So, by rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\,\operatorname{Im}(f)=\dim V-\dim\,\operatorname{ker}(f)=\dim V$ and hence $\operatorname{Im}(f)=V$, i.e. $f$ is surjective. Alternatively, since $f$ is injective, $\operatorname{ker}(f)=0$. So $\det(f)\not=0$ and $f$ is invertible (hence bijective).

Answer (score 1):

Oops, missed the homework tag first time around.

First find a formula for $\det f$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$.

> First, suppose that $A$ has a full set of eigenvectors. Let $A u_k = \lambda u_k $ and let $v_k^* A = \lambda_k v_k^*$. Then it is straightforward to show that $f(u_j v_j^*) = (1+ \lambda_i {\lambda_j})u_j v_j^*$, from which we obtain $\det f = \prod_{i,j} (1+\lambda_i {\lambda_j})$. It follows by a continuity argument that this formula holds for arbitrary $A$.

Second, show that $\det f \neq 0$.

> Since $A^m = \alpha I$, it follows that for any eigenvalue, we have $\lambda^m = \alpha$, hence $|\lambda| = \sqrt[m]{|\alpha|}$. Hence $|\lambda_i \lambda_k| = (\sqrt[m]{|\alpha|})^2 \neq 1$, and hence $(1+\lambda_i {\lambda_j}) \neq 0$ for all $i,j$. So we have $\det f \neq 0$. Hence $f$ is bijective.

Comment: It's not quite a homework, but I tagged it as it is, because it is still about school. Actually I've been working for a math contest and I ran into this problem. I'm still trying to fully understand your answer, it seems to be legit, but it's me who isn't yet perfectly able to understand

Comment: Well, the hints above are fairly strong, try using them first...

Comment: Of course, thank you for them, didn't ask you to solve it. Just wanted to clarify why I tagged it as homework.

Comment: Often the form of $f$ will suggest the eigenvalue form. So $X \mapsto X+AXA$ suggests eigenvalues of the form $1+\lambda_i \lambda_j$. The rest is details...

Comment: There is just one thing I am not sure about. Why is that if $det f \ne 0$ f is bijective?

Comment: Because if $\det f \neq 0$, then Cramer's rule gives an explicit formula for an inverse.

Comment: @BujancaMihai: Did something happen?

Comment: Please don't take it personally, but I just got back to this question and the other proof seemed easier to understand. Just found out today at school that I don't fully understand this, I tried to explain it to someone and got a bit stuck, however the injectivity demonstration was quite nice.
Sorry for that and sincere thanks for your help-- it's just that.. i think i'm not really at a high level, especially with problems about matrices

Comment: @BujancaMihai: It is not an issue, I was just curious why. Your comment answers! The other proof is far more direct for your purposes. I thought it was cute to actually compute the determinant.